# How to call a specific list item in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just messing around and trying to learn javascript right now.
Basically, I built a website that has a big picture in the middle and you press a previous or next button and it switches accordingly.

Now I want to push a button and make it go to a specific image.

I currently have 3 items that contain
`<div class="slider">` and 1 of the images has its own `<div class="goat">` inside of the "slider" class.

Right now I only know how to use things like:

```
var currentSlide = $('.slide').last();
```

How would I make it so rather than `last()`, it selects the goat image?

Comment: This is a _very_ basic jQuery question. Please take the time to read a tutorial or [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) before asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many ways you could do this. Personally, I wouldnt have all the images in the markup at all. Since you're only showing one at a time, there is no need for it. Instead, I'd use an array of urls and just set them to a single image tag as needed.

### Helpful documentation:

[Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

[jQuery .click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

[jQuery .hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

[jQuery .attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[jQuery .index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

[jQuery .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

[$(this)](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified)

A simple example might be:

```js
// create an array of image urls
var images = [
  'http://avatarmaker.net/free-avatars/avatars/various_227/yellow_duck_avatar_100x100_48557.jpg',
  'http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/ned_flanders.gif',
  'http://www.sclakes.com/forums/download/file.php?avatar=853.png',
  'http://avatarmaker.net/free-avatars/avatars/cartoons_229/the_simpsons_254/mr_burns_sneaky_avatar_100x100_14710.gif',
  'http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/super_mario_panic.gif',
  ];
// create a global variable to keep up with the currently displayed image index
var current=0;

  
/*  handle prev and next buttons */
  
  
  // bind a function to the change event of all buttons with the class `change`
  // make sure botht the prev and next buttons have that calss
$('.change').click(function(){
    // when one of the buttons is clicked, check if the button also has the class `next` and act accordingly
    if($(this).hasClass('next')){
        // next line is a ternary expression
        // it basically says - check if adding 1 to current will make curent greater than the length of the images array 
        // if so, reset current to 0 
        // otherwise increment current by one
        current= current+1 > images.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
        
    }
    else{
        // same as before except - check if subtracting one from current will make curent less than 0 
        // if so, reset the last image in the array 
        // otherwise decrement current by one
        current= current-1 < 0 ? images.length-1 : current-1;
        
    }
    // set the src attribute of the image tag to the url stored at the `current` index of the image array
    $('#myImage').attr('src',images[current])
});






/*  handle selecting specific images if you want a button for every possible image*/


$('.changeToIndex').click(function(){
    // get the index of the clicked button
    var current = $('.changeToIndex').index($(this));
  
    // set the src attribute of the image tag to the url stored at the `current` index of the image array
    $('#myImage').attr('src',images[current]); 
  
});





/*  handle selecting specific images if you DONT want a button for every possible image*/


$('.changeToImage').click(function(){
    // get the `data-to-image` value of the clicked button
    var current = $(this).data('to-image');
  
    // set the src attribute of the image tag to the url stored at the `current` index of the image array
    $('#myImage').attr('src',images[current]); 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="myImage" src="http://avatarmaker.net/free-avatars/avatars/various_227/yellow_duck_avatar_100x100_48557.jpg" alt="" height="100" width="100"><br><br>


<button class="change prev">Previous</button><button class="change next">next</button>


<br><br>
<button class="changeToIndex">Image 1 </button>
<button class="changeToIndex">Image 2 </button>
<button class="changeToIndex">Image 3</button>
<button class="changeToIndex">Image 4</button>
<button class="changeToIndex">Image 5</button>


<br><br>
<button class="changeToImage" data-to-image="3"> Mr. Burns </button>
<button class="changeToImage" data-to-image="1"> Flanders </button>
```